# css animation on floated inline div's

Tags: html, css, css-float, inline, css-animations

I've long used this site to help me out with my CSS and HTML, but now I seem to have come up against a bug that I can't find an answer to:

I have a load of left floated div's in a parent div that is centred on the page. I've made a 3D hover effect for some of these divs using shadows and shifting the margins. I've then animated the hover with css transitions.

My problem is that during the animation the div floated to the left of the hover sort of wobbles a bit by a couple of pixels.. At the end state of the animation it is in the right place its just during the transition..

I'm thinking this is because the div is floated and inline, which can't really be changed. But the margin on the left reduces at the same rate as the margin on the right does so why do the div's surrounding it wobble about? :(

I've made a Fiddle showing the problem here http://jsfiddle.net/9jqbX/

```
<div class="wrapper">

<div class="cube4 threedeehover"></div>
<div class="cube4 threedeehover"></div>
<div class="cube4 threedeehover"></div>
<div class="cube4 threedeehover"></div>
```

```
.wrapper {                          position: relative;
                                width: 960px;
                                margin-right: auto;
                                margin-left: auto;
                                padding-left: 10px;
                                padding-right: 10px;
                                padding-bottom: 20px; }

.cube4 {
                                float: left;
                                min-height: 1px;
                                position: relative;
                                margin-top: 20px;
                                margin-left: 10px;
                                margin-right: 10px;
                                width: 180px;
                                height: 180px;
                                overflow: hidden; padding: 20px;
                                background:#347ec9; }


.threedeehover {                    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
                                -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
                                -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
                                -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
                                transition: all 0.3s ease; }

.threedeehover:hover {              box-shadow: 
                                1px 1px 0px 0px #fff,
                                2px 2px 0px 0px #eee,
                                3px 3px 0px 0px #fff,
                                4px 4px 0px 0px #eee,
                                5px 5px 0px 0px #fff,
                                6px 6px 0px 0px #eee,
                                7px 7px 0px 0px #fff,
                                8px 8px 0px 0px #eee,
                                9px 9px 0px 0px #adadad,   /*3D bottom border colour*/
                                5px 5px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);}

.cube4.threedeehover:hover {        margin-top: 11px; 
                                margin-left: 0px; 
                                margin-right:20px; }
```

I'm using Safari 7.05 in OSX 10.9.4,
Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: I don’t see any wobbling. If this happens in a specific browser, please give name, version & OS.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Safari 7.0.5 on OSX 10.9.4

Comment: after a couple of hours trying to work this out it seems to be a bug in the Safari Browser. It doesn't happen in Chrome,  Opera or IE so I've reported it to Apple as a bug and using the code as is.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's Safari's issue, yes.

Try to use `translate` instead of `margin`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nikoloza/9jqbX/1/

Answer (score 0):

After the latest update to Safari this issue has disappeared, so I've concluded that it was a webkit bug rather than anything to do with my code.